# How can I use mod_rewrite to sanitize my input?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm setting up an apache virtualhost, and I want it to redirect all requests to index.php passing as a parameter the original URL if matches a specific pattern.

Considering the pattern is (quote-less) "PaTTern[0-9]", this is what I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(PaTTern[0-9]).*$ /index.php?$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

What I am getting is an Error 500. Any ideas?

Comment: The last line is most probably causing rewrite loop (since it is unconditional), try just removing it

Comment: But I want to redirect anything else to index.php (without the argument). How can I get that done? :-/

Comment: Ah, so: if (pattern_matched) then (redirect to index.php?pattern) else (redirect to index.php)? Then add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$` above your last line

Comment: Works like a charm! can you post it as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line is most probably causing rewrite loop (since it is unconditional).
Since you don't want any rewrites in case the request already goes to `/index.php`, add another condition:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(PaTTern[0-9]).*$ /index.php?$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [NC,L]
```